# How to add a notification next to custom admin menu?

Tags: admin-menu

I want to show a notification bubble next to a custom menu name on admin dashboard.

It's a custom admin menu, And the notification will be showing a custom value from the Database.

Something like when there is a new WordPress update:
[image: WordPress New Version Update Notification Screenshot]

How to do that?

Comment: you just have to add the HTML code for the number in the 2nd argument of `add_menu_page`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add notification bubble for my custom admin menu page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298481/how-to-add-notification-bubble-for-my-custom-admin-menu-page)